# what is the difference between Radeon Software Crimson and AMD Catalyst Control Center

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I recently purchased Hp 15-ab027tx which comes with **Radeon R7 M360** gpu and installed AMD catalyst control center. When i checked AMD website,I noticed to download **Radeon Software Crimson** for notebooks.

My question is what is the difference between these two and will i have to uninstall AMD catalyst control center in my laptop to install Radeon Software Crimson.

Comment: The version of the software.  AMD renamed and rebranded the software in late 2015

Comment: @Ramhound: Looks like a valid answer, dont't it?

Comment: so which is better: uninstall catalyst control center first and then install Radeon Software Crimson or just install it to avoid any installation error

Comment: This is a great question to self-answer

Answer (score 4):

Comments pretty much covered the gist but here's an answer anyway... AMD Radeon Software Crimson Edition is the new Control Panel software for AMD graphics cards. It's basically a UI upgrade from the Catalyst Control Center (CCC) and comes with a good amount of bug fixes.

In the comments you asked if you should uninstall the CCC before installing Crimson and that would be a good idea. To be on the safe side, create a restore point before uninstalling CCC and then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion, Catalyst Control Center(CCC) is better than the Crimson.
I recently updated to Crimson and noticed a huge change in graphical performance, my games started to lag a lot and wasn't delivering as good performance as before with the catalyst control center.
So, my suggestion would be to keep using Catalyst Control Center.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed, or digged through a similar question on the NVidia side with older GPUs (specifically a 8800 GTS) and there was a consensus that older drivers are better optimized for older gpus.
While you will find support for your gpu in the new rendition of the program, it's probably just an out of focus compatibility link between the new program and an otherwise old driver.

TL;DR Catalyst control center latest version is more likely to be optimized for the older driver than the Crimson Edition.
And this goes for any program out there.